# Create a Watson Assistant chatbot for websites and Facebook Messenger

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

Designing a Watson Assistant chatbot for a website and Facebook Messenger raises some issues due to the different way these channels format the Watson response. I am trying to understand how to deal with this.

Currently, a Watson Assistant dialog node allows responses that include text, image, pause, and an option. So far so good. The problem is that in text response I need:

1. add some empty line. In HTML I can use `<br/>` and it works fine on Website but not on Facebook.
2. add a link. In HTML I use `<a href="">link</a>` while Facebook Messenger render directly the single URL
3. I need to list an unordered or ordered list. In HTML I can use `ol/li` or `ul/li` tags in Facebook messenger no.
4. carriage return. In HTML I can use `<br/>` in Facebook see 1.

How do I deal with these incompatibilities?

I expect to have somewhere best practices documented to write a multi-channel chatbot but I haven't found them.

Answer (score 1):

When building a chatbot with IBM Watson Assistant that has to face different output channels (in your case website and Facebook Messenger), I see two options:

1. Limit the responses to the common output features. Watson Assistant supports [rich responses](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-overview#dialog-overview-multimedia) with multi-line support. Use that instead of `<br/>`. Check with the integration-specific docs, here [Facebook Messenger integration](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-facebook#deploy-facebook-dialog), what is supported.
2. Use two bots, one for the website and one for Facebook Messenger. In that case you could use the [native response format](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-responses-json#dialog-responses-json-native) supported by Watson Assistant. The downside is that you have to maintain two bots.
3. (not an option from your description) Add a wrapper around Watson Assistant and translate your generic responses to your desired output channel with optimized formatting. It would require more effort, but has the best output.

As a common format, consider some basic [Markdown as supported by Watson Assistan and some output channels](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-overview).

Comment: How I can do the option 3?

Comment: Use one of the SDKs (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/) to write the wrapper app. That app could also interface with other services.

Comment: I am still working on the problem and it's really incredible that they created a multi-channel service and didn't consider a way to render a link that works on every integration. Now I have HTML link that works fine in Wordpress plugin but  no on Facebook, on the opposite side Facebook render well plain URL but Wordpress plugin. This is my problem now.

Comment: I added a snippet on Markdown to my answer.  It seems that it works for some basic (bold, italics, hyperlink" across most channels.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for

Comment: You said: "I added a snippet on Markdown to my answer. It seems that it works for some basic (bold, italics, hyperlink" across most channels.". I replied, "Can you give me an example?". I mean a sample code that I can use as an example.

Comment: The linked "Markdown as supported ..." has examples. The Stack Overflow Q&A are in Markdown

Comment: That markdown worked neither with Wordpress plugin nor Facebook. I tested it.

Comment: Having a similar issue related to the Transfer to Human Agent scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64671882/watson-assistant-connected-to-messenger-connect-to-human-agent